# When can a batsman change from batting left handed to right handed?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, trivia, icc

Some shots in one-day or Twenty 20 cricket involve the batsman changing stance to play a shot (e.g. reverse sweep), but are there any provisions in cricket laws that allow the umpire to decide when this can take place because then the wide and lbw decisions also need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 6):

Batsmen can go for reverse sweep or switch hit any time during the match. Umpires have nothing to decide with it.

ICC had already [made this shot legal](http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/cricket/18299652) and the changes were done [with the rules](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci-icc/content/story/564249.html) of LBW and wide for these shots.